# CSS Printing: @page size ignored IE10

Tags: css, printing, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to improve print functionality in an Orgchart application I developed.

It is working very well in chrome using the @page {size:L W} parameter, however IE10 seems to be ignoring the sizes ive defined completely.

```
@page {
    size:21in 14in; 
    margin:.5cm;
}
```

Note: my paper is not actually 21x14 :P im using that size to force the browser to interpret the print area differently for my divs that just cut off otherwise.

Works fantastic in chrome, but IE is hellbent on defaulting to portrait.

Advice?

Answer (score 1):

IE 6,7,8,9,10 does not have support for CSS3 "size" property:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508(v=vs.85).aspx

Tested in IE11 too. Guess what? Not working.